# Flexbox with rowspan and fixed aspect ratio

Tags: css, grid, html-table, flexbox

I’m hoping this can be done with flexbox and not require (too much) trickery.

What I’m looking for:

1) One large block, with two smaller ones next to it that rowspan, without having to have their own nested wrap. [Working Example](http://codepen.io/vkjgr/pen/OPRPRR/)

2) Percentage width that resizes at a fixed aspect ratio, probably using the padding-top/bottom trick. This can either be defined on just the large block, the smaller ones, or both. I say either/or/and because I don’t really care so much that the smaller block match the aspect ratio of the larger one. Perhaps the aspect ratio could only be applied to the larger block, and the smaller ones would flex to the height. That would be fine, as long as they all resize together, relative to the width of the container. [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sxxbqtnb/7/)

That last bit is where I’m hitting the major road block. The first example with a rowspan looks great, but relies on the wrap having a defined height, which breaks the responsiveness. When I try controlling the height of the blocks rather than the wrapper, things start breaking down.

Here’s my non-working [work in progress](http://codepen.io/chasebank/pen/yYBYOZ/) (or below)

Thanks!

```
<div class="gallery">
   <div class="gallery-group">
       <div class="a"></div>
       <div class="b"></div>
       <div class="c"></div>
   </div>
</div>

.gallery {
   position: relative;
   height: auto;
   margin: 0 12%;
   background-color: transparent;
   display: flex;
}

.gallery-group {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   flex-direction: column;

   width: 100%;
   list-style: none;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   font-size: 0;
   align-items: stretch;
   flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.a, .b {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  align-self: flex-start;
  width:30%;
  padding-top:22%;
}

.c {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  align-self: flex-end;
  width:70%;
  padding-top:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it, I re-sized it in and out of CodePen.io. The left column always maintained 35% width and 50% of height on the green and red flex-items. The right column maintained the 65% width and 100% height as well. Take a look here:

[**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/01/pen/NGKZme)

**CSS**

```
.gallery {
   position: fixed;
   background-color: transparent;
   display: flex;
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   flex-flow: column wrap;

}

.gallery-group {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   flex-direction: row;
   align-self: stretch;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: relative;
}


.a, .b {
   flex: 1 1 1%;
   width: 35%;
   height: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
}

.a { top: 0px }
.b { bottom: 0px }

.c {
   flex: 1 1 1%;
   align-self: stretch;
   width: 65%;
   padding-top: 35%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0px;
}

.a { background: red; }
.b { background: green; }
.c { background: blue; }
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding. That's pretty close! You got them properly aligned, and they're keeping their width. The only issue is the fixed height on the gallery/group, which throws off the aspect ratio. Here's what I'm looking for using positioning, which works fine, but I've been curious if flexbox could simpify things: http://codepen.io/chasebank/pen/RWNgXV

Comment: @Chase it works beautifully, My 2 cents: First, if you're going to add text, try using `rem` for `font-size` and add this rule set :`font: 400 16px/1.45 Arial;` everything but `16px/1.45` is arbitrary. Try not to use `em` for text or media queries just use it for responsive structure. Second thing, I know CodePen's LESS compiler used all of those vendor prefixes on the flexbox properties, but afaik most of that is deprecated. Currently,  flexbox is supported by all the important browsers and the only prefix still required  is `-webkit` for Safari. http://caniuse.com/flexbox